# Windows 10:Jupyter notebook not launching

Tags: anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 3 in windows 10 system. And when I try to to launch Jupyter notebook from Anaconda navigator app, notebook console doesn't open up in browser.

And when I try from Anaconda prompt, I get:

'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

How to get it working?

Comment: Did you add your python paths to your path variables?

Comment: I haven't installed python separately. I assume anaconda has its python installations.